# Lauch iOS app from TestFlight is crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, build, testflight

I have my iOS App at TestFlight. I installed it in my iPad. After the installation. I opened the application by tapping 'open' button. It started launching the app with splash screen and then crashed.

But launching the app manually tapping the app icon works fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it was a TestFlight issue. Try to get crash logs from your device to see what happened: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH21-SW3

Comment: If you have a live app already in your iPad and you install another build using TestFlight, App can result into crash.

Comment: @Juan, i am having the same issue, did know why is it happening? Do you still face it or it is solved? Please let me know

Comment: Shanmugaraja G : have you resolved this issue, If please let me know i have the same issue

Comment: Did you able to resolve this issue, if so, please let me know i am facing the same issue.