# App crashes from testflight only for the first time, building it with xcode and using diawi, the app is working fine without any crashes

Tags: swift, xcode

The application is crashing only for the first time when installed from testflight, while it is working fine without any crash while building it with xcode also tried uploading build from diawi, work fine there too.

How can find where the crash is, or what is the cause of the crash?

I have had walkthrough to many links, like enabling/disabling the bitcode for the respective third party library, changing the build configuration to Release etc,, but none of them was helpful to me

[Lauch iOS app from TestFlight is crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659442/lauch-ios-app-from-testflight-is-crashing)

Well this post describes the issue that i am facing,opening the app from testflight app, by clicking on the open button cause the crash

Please help me out

Thanks

Comment: What was the error message? Did you eve get the crash log off the device?

Comment: No, i tried going onto window->devices-> select device , but i am not getting any crash for the particular app, moreover my app is not listed in the installed apps list .

Comment: I want to refactor my question, i am facing the same issue as this guy is facing, please refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659442/lauch-ios-app-from-testflight-is-crashing